# Что делает Ord?

Tags: pascal

Есть код:

```
var
i: integer; // объявляем
begin
n := 0; // объявляем в 10 системе
for i := 1 to Length(s) do //цикл Length(s) определяет текущую длину строки
if s[i] in ['0'..'7'] // от 0 до 7 могу ввести число
then n := n * 8 + ord(s[i]) - ord('0') // 
else exit; // выход
vosem := true;
end;

var
s: string; // объявление
n: longint; // объявление
begin
Write('Введите число в восьмеричной системе: '); ReadLn(s); // вывод
if vosem(s, n) // вызов функции
then WriteLn(s, '(8) = ', n, '(10)') // вывод 8 и 10
else
WriteLn('*** Плохое число'); // вывод
end.
```

Что делает
`then n := n * 8 + ord(s[i]) - ord('0') что в i и для чего - ord('0').`
Нужно было и 8 в 10 систему счисления.

Comment: В справке никак не получилось посмотреть? ``ord()`` возвращает ascii код переданного символа.

Answer (score 2):

KoVadim ваш ответ совсем не верен.

**Функция `Ord` возвращает "Порядковое число".**

Что касается ASCII символа (как в примере) то это индекс символа.

Но так-же функция `Ord` может работать с другими типами данных например enum.

```
program Hello;

type
  TDigits = (dgOne, dgTwo, dgThree);

begin
  Write('Ordinal index: ', Ord(dgTwo));
end.
```

Вернёт

```
Ordinal index: 1
```

Comment: да, она определена и для энумов. я расписывал текущий вопрос автора. Уточню и Ваш ответ. Я считаю, что перевод "Порядковое число" - это неудачный перевод. В английском там number скорее всего и я бы это перевел как номер. То есть "порядковый номер". Когда то это знание помогло мне решить большую бажинку в коде:) Просто сравните "maximum number of descriptor" vs "maximum number**s** of descriptor**s**"

Answer (score 1):

`Ord` - это функция, которая берет символ (char) и переводит его в ASCII код. Благодаря тому, что цифры в ASCII упорядочены от 0 до 9, вычитая с кода символа значения кода нуля, можно получить собственно само число.

Comment: Достаточно мутно сформулировано ..